# DRF use field-value instead of default (pk) in POST request

Tags: python-3.x, api, post, serialization, django-rest-framework

Trying send valid POST request.

It's works when i send like this:

```
{
  "name":"but",
  "sklad":1
}
```

Response is something like this, all is valid:

```
{
  "name": "but",
  "getsklad": "fence"
}
```

But when I'm trying send this, with 'fence':

```
{
  "name":"but",
  "sklad":"fence"
}
```

Got error:

```
Invalid type. The primary key value was expected, str was received.
```

Have this piece of code in models.py:

```
class Sklad(models.Model):
    storages = (
        ('fence', 'Забор'),
        ('sett', 'Тротуарка'),
    )
    storage = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=storages, 
        help_text='Name of storage',
        default='sett'
    )

class Zabor(models.Model):
    sklad = models.ForeignKey(Sklad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ...
```

This in serializers.py:

```
class ZaborPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Zabor
        fields = ( 
              ...
            'name',
            'sklad',
        )
```

And Views.py part:

```
class ZaborView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ZaborPostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'status': 'Success'})
        else:
            return Response({'status': 'Failed'})
```

I know what when i write '1' in request, this means 'pk'. But how I can send name rather than the id/pk?

I am beginner. So don't kick me hard for stupid questions)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are providing the `Sklad` *FOREIGN_KEY*, which is unique you can filter by that value only with one type: integer, string, etc.

You can set the `storage` field of `Sklad` to the primary key:

```
class Sklad(models.Model):
    storages = (
        ('fence', 'Забор'),
        ('sett', 'Тротуарка'),
    )
    storage = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=storages, 
        help_text='Name of storage',
        default='sett',
        primary_key=True
    )
```

Now you can directly filter with your string value.

Another option is to filter in the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import Http404

class ZaborView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        dataDict = dict(request.data)
        try:
            sklad = get_object_or_404(Sklad.objects, storage=dataDict['sklad'][0])
            serializer = ZaborPostSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response({'status': 'Success'})
            else:
                return Response({'status': 'Failed'})
        except Http404:
            return Response({'status': 'Failed'})
```

Note that it will only work if you have only one `Sklad` with the given `storage` field.
If you have multiple ones you can pick the first one, since you do not supply a primary key and you have not other fields to filter:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

.....
sklad = list(get_list_or_404(Sklad.objects, storage=dataDict['sklad'][0]))[0]
.....
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Very useful, thanks bro. Some time after post this question I was go to the documentation and find there one thing. 'to_field' option of ForeignKey relationship field that filter related model by selected field. Requires 'unique=True' option in selected field. Works as expected. What you think about this?

Comment: unique=True makes sense, because there must be some way to uniquely define the ForeignKey. Imagine you had multiple Sklads with the storage 'fence'. Which one should the Zabor serializer pick ? Your solution is better because it does not make the storage field a PrimaryKey. Thanks for the info !